# Are there any recent PHP Manuals, the CHMs with the user-contributed notes out there?

Tags: php

Are there any recent PHP Manuals, the CHMs with the user-contributed notes out there?

The PHP guys seem to have **'dropped support'** for them.

Are some of them lurking around the PHP website itself, accessible by their unlinked URLs only?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [How to host the php.net manual on your laptop for offline use](http://www.jaisenmathai.com/blog/2009/03/03/how-to-host-the-phpnet-manual-on-your-laptop-for-offline-use/).

Answer (score 0):

W3 schools also has examples of most functions.